# Why my Eevee render result is transparent?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, transparency

I downloaded recent version of the blender 2.91 today and I tried to render the default image with default render engine. But I could find a transparent output instead of the square. Anything I need to change in setup. output[image: render result] I am using Radeon GPU
[image: I am using Radeon GPU]

Comment: try a factory reset (File > Defaults > Load factory settings)

Comment: I’m having the same problem in the shader view ports. But in cycles it renders fine. By any chance are you running a Radeon gpu![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejJtj.jpg)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ8Z4.jpg)

Comment: Yes!! Radeon should not be used (need to be uninstalled)? or need to use any work around for Radeon GPU?

Comment: @Mobin, I tried  but not working, Should be the Radeon GPU problem. Any help on that is appreciated.

Comment: Which Radeon? Have a look here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#amd

Comment: Cycles it renders fine, Problem is with Eevee only

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your user preferences, "system" part?

Comment: Can also try to update your openGL driver as indicated here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/gpu/windows/intel.html (Eeeve uses openGL).

Comment: Well there is a Radeon renderer addon but blender worked just fine before. I wonder if it was a Radeon update or a blender update. Because I’ve been running blender on Radeon for the past year with no problems

Comment: I uninstalled blender and reinstalled like 5 times. I even full reset my computer. And it’s still stuck.

Comment: I just uninstalled the Radeon Software, now it works fine for me.